# wifi printing in android

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-wifi

I want to print file using wifi printing in my android application.I have scanned wifi printer and i am having wifi printer IP address . Now how can i transfer file from android phone to printer to print it ? I am using following code to transfer file to printer `public void uploadFile(File fileName){

```
     FTPClient client = new FTPClient();
    try {
        client.connect(FTP_HOST,21);
        client.login(FTP_USER, FTP_PASS);
        client.setType(FTPClient.TYPE_BINARY);
        client.changeDirectory("/");
        client.upload(fileName, new MyTransferListener());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        try {
            client.disconnect(true);    
        } catch (Exception e2) {
            e2.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}`
```

Can anybody help me ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can might do it without sending whole file, just pick the Strings from the file and make connection with the wifi device, send the text to the device, it will print it. I have done same thing with the bluetooth printer.

Comment: :Yes,We can send string from file then which protocol do we need to use?  Any idea ?

Comment: you can use http connection, and send string using DataOutputSteam.

Comment: I am having problem with pairing devices using bluetooth.Can you help me? I have implemented code from android developer site .

Answer (score 3):

Using **Socket** you can print from android using network printer in WIFI Connection

```
Socket objSocket = new Socket();
String sIP = "192.168.1.10"
String sPort = "9100"
InetSocketAddress objEndPoint = new InetSocketAddress(sIP, Integer.parseInt(sPort));

DataOutputStream objOutputStream;

objSocket.connect(objEndPoint, 3000);

objOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(objSocket.getOutputStream());
objOutputStream.write(("Test Print").getBytes());

objOutputStream.close();
objSocket.close();
```

Comment: can u tell me how to format content if i want to print no of line like table of 3 column and no of line like receipt , i am trying to do this using \n\t but if any of my item had more or words it misplace all other items

Comment: i simply want to wrap content how can i

Comment: Hai Lenda, Just formatting string variable line by line (Lines defends on your page width) and append string to the common StringBuffer variable. finally send the string buffer value to printing (If you needed add printer command string also append in string buffer class)  Example: String sStr = "This is a Sample file"  ; StringBuffer sbFinalString = new StringBuffer(); sbFinalString.append(sStr); sbFinalString.append("\n\n");         sStr = "written by venkat"; sbFinalString.append(sStr); Print(sbFinalString.toString()); Hope this helps....

Comment: but to wrap i in one colum have much more content